# What's a recommended way of building for many versions of a 3rd party library?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

Our application depends on a 3rd party library with multiple versions (v1, v2, v3, etc). We would like to have a separate build for each of these versions.

One approach is to create a different build configuration for each version (e.g., Debug-1, Debug-2, Release-1, Release-2, etc.), where each configuration conditionally references the correct 3rd party library version. However, this results in an explosion of build configurations, which is undesirable.

Another approach is to introduce a new project property, such as "LibVersion", and conditionally reference the correct 3rd party library version based on that value. For example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LibVersion>2</LibVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Lib-1" Condition=" '$(LibVersion)' == '1' " />
    <Reference Include="Lib-2" Condition=" '$(LibVersion)' == '2' " />
</ItemGroup>
```

With this approach, we would just have "Debug" and "Release" as the Configuration. However, editing "LibVersion" in order to build within Visual Studio is more difficult since, as far as I know, it can't be done in Visual Studio.

Are there better ways of handling my issue? Or, if using the second approach, would it make sense to create a Visual Studio extension to allow editing of this property? Or perhaps make this property an environment variable rather than a project property?

Comment: Is the 3rd party library in the form of a separate DLL for each version?

Comment: _"as far as I know, it can't be done in Visual Studio."_ - what do you mean? You can edit .csproj in VS. You can create publish profile to use different values for `LibVersion` on publish. Also you can consider using constants instead of `LibVersion` prop (i.e. define constants like `LibVersion_1`, `LibVersion_2` ...)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, it is.

Comment: @GuruStron I meant that it's not easy to edit a custom property in Visual Studio without opening the .csproj file (as easy as changing the Configuration or Platform). Using constants is a good idea since they can more easily be changed in the project properties window.

Comment: Double-clicking the ".csproj" file and then editing `<LibVersion>` seems pretty easy?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Fair enough (though in Visual Studio I have to right-click, then choose "Unload Project"). I was hoping for something more visible and obvious to the developer.

Comment: If you have to right-click and "unload project" then you must be using the legacy format and not the SDK-style format. I strongly recommend upgrading your projects to SDK-style. You can do this piecemeal (i.e. one-by-one) as you have time. (Unless it's a ClickOnce project - I don't think SDK-style supports those). Note that SDK-style projects do support .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for the recommendation. We're still on .NET Framework 4.0 because our clients are stuck with that. Do SDK-style projects support .NET Framework 4.0?

Comment: Yes they do: `<TargetFramework>net40</TargetFramework>`

Comment: Change your default definition to `<LibVersion Condition="'$(LibVersion)' == ''">2</LibVersion>` so that you can set the property from elsewhere. Properties can be specified on the msbuild command line, e.g. `-p: LibVersion=3`. But the command line won't help with Visual Studio. In your project add a conditional import of another msbuild file, e.g. create a `LibVerProps` property with a value of 'LibVersion.props' and import the file if it exists `<Import Project="$(LibVerProps)" Condition="Exists('$(LibVerProps)')"/>`. Create or edit the LibVersion.props file to set the `LibVersion` property.

Comment: If desired, 'LibVersion.props' can be added to the set of ignored files so that it is not committed to version control. If there is interest, I can expand on this approach in an answer.

Comment: @JonathanDodds I thought the command-line property values override those in the project, so I may not need the default definition, unless it helps with something else. In any case, I like your idea of importing the `LibVersion` from a file that can be more easily edited by developers. I'm still thinking of writing a VS extension to add a drop-down menu to the toolbar with a list of `LibVersion` values.

Comment: @redcurry You are correct. When defined on the command line `LibVersion` will be global. Just as a matter of style/convention, I always add the `Condition` (which is described in ["MSBuild best practices"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-best-practices?view=vs-2022)).